# Loop Through Columns to Insert SUM Formula

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have a program where I need to find the sum of columns 7 through 30 (G through AD). What I am trying to do is loop through and insert the formula (=SUM(Columns(i)2:Columns(i)1000)) but obviously Columns(i) is not the letter but the number. This is not complying with the format required by SUM so I'm wondering what I can do instead.

I have a program where old sheets will be deleted and new ones added holding configuration data for a product. This means formulas cannot be in the sheet inself or any other sheet referring to it. Prices will be held in columns G through P and U through AD which I need to find the total for and place it in row 1 above the corresponding data. When I try:

```
       For i = 7 To 30
            wsNewSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = "=SUM(" & Columns(i).Select & "2:" & Columns(i).Select & "1000)"
        Next i
```

Columns(i) is returning as "True" for some reason. I have also tried to place the totals in a different sheet as the new sheets (wsNewSheet) were being created.

```
            For i = 2 To 30
            For f = 7 To 30
                wsTotals.Cells(1, i).Value = "=SUM(" & wsNewSheet & "!" & Columns(f).Select & "2:" & Columns(f).Select & "1000)"
            Next f
        Next i
```

However, this did not work either. This statement returned "Run-time error '438.' Object doesn't support this property or method." I attemped to do research on this error, but could not fix my situation. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need loop here, use single line instead:

```
Range("G1:AD1").Formula = "=SUM(G2:G1000)"
```

Excel automatically adjust formulas:

- in `G1` you'd have `=SUM(G2:G1000)`
- in `H1` you'd have `=SUM(H2:H1000)`
- ....
- in `AD1` you'd have `=SUM(AD2:AD1000)`

Comment: I knew I was making it much harder than it needed to be. Thank you very much.